# Submit form with flask wtforms with GET method

Tags: python, forms, flask, wtforms

I have 2 routes :

```
@app.route('/activity', methods=["GET"])
def addactivity():
    return render_template('activity.html')
```

In acitvity.html I have a form with some fields and I want to submit this form to another route :

```
@app.route('/students', methods=["GET"])
def addstudents():
    return render_template('students.html')
```

So when I submit the form in acitvity.html I will be redirected to

/students?field1=value1&field2=value2 etc...

For activity form i am using wtforms with validators: DataRequired() or InputRequired()

The problem is that when i am using form.validate() in addstudents route even if form is validated or not it will redirect me to students.html route.I want in case the form is not validated to display the errors in activity.html.How is that possible?

I am new to flask and maybe my whole code is wrong, but the concept is that if the activity form is validated i will be redirected to the students route, if not errors will be displayed in activity route..
Furthermore i need to submit the the form in students route with the args of the previous form.

Comment: You have to "POST" forms, unless i missed something

Comment: You need `if request.method == "POST"` inside your definition, then put your form validation there. At the end it should be `return redirect(url_for('students'))`

Comment: can you add your form.py code?

Comment: @SuperStew A form can be submitted with `POST` or `GET`, depending on the `method` attribute on the `form` element.  You might use `GET` for things like search forms, which are not going to cause a change on the server side.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form

Comment: Can you add the whole code in add student?

Answer (score 8):

You need to pass `request.args` when you initialize your form, e.g.

```
@app.route('/students')
def addstudents():
    form = Form(request.args)

    if form.validate():
        return render_template('students.html')

    # Redirect to addactivity if form is invalid
    return redirect(url_for('addactivity'))
```

You will need to import the `request` object from `flask`.

Source: https://github.com/lepture/flask-wtf/issues/291

To redirect to `addstudents` when the form is submitted, add the attribute `action="{{ url_for('addstudents') }}"` to the `<form>` tag in `activity.html`.